# STM32F030CCT6 BOOT

Tags: stm32, bootloader

Im doing my first schematic with STM32. I want to use STM32F030CCT6. However im not really sure what to do it's BOOT0. I have googled STM32 schematics and they all have BOOT0 and BOOT1. Mine have only BOOT0. Checked all pins. Obviously i could just put a jumper so i can later give it Vcc or GND. But i would like to know why it has only one BOOT but other similar chips have two. Im also using UART to USB chip so i would like to program it over UART as well and read serial data.

Comment: In all of your googling did you find [the Manual](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f030cc.html#resource)?

Comment: Some of the older chips have two pins but one has been the norm for years now.  Leaving configurable strapping is best, you can ground it if you will never use the bootloader but alongside an SWD connect-under-reset setup it is another way to recover from certain mis-flashings.

Comment: I have teached to read manual always first. Of course i read it. I just needed to be sure that im not missing something because it was really weird that it doesn't have BOOT1. Thanks for the answer Chris.